# Can't update Microsoft Edge

Tags: apt, 20.04, microsoft

If I run sudo apt update after installing Microsoft edge I get this window.
[image: Screenshot of the terminal]

Comment: Did you run `curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -` before updating?

Comment: I uninstalled edge and then install EDGE by following their terminal instruction and it worked, No problem now